# Why use NoSQL at all?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I started experimenting with node.js a while ago and among other things, created a table out of the content of a .json file.
That got me thinking. If node.js is working on the server side, and the end user isn't exposed to the url of the .json file, why use a NoSQL (ex. Mongodb) at all? why not just hold folders of json files (as tables) and query them using javascript?
Is there still a security issue?

Comment: A database is a bit more complex than a bunch of JSON files

Comment: I understand that. and yet, why not just use a bunch of JSON files?

Comment: if data is not going to change - then yes, use JSON files. otherwise DB is more suitable

Comment: Well, let's go to basics, querying JSON files which contains maybe about 350 MB of data will not be easy, specially if you need fast and complex querying which will take indexes

Comment: Database have best data structure algorithm which help to search and find data at efficient way and you can used sharding and clustering in nosql when your  data set is large and you can also provide various type security at database level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? That's what you'd be doing using a file system based approach. Someone's already written something to store, query, and retrieve your JSON data and scale.

A small project that you're only running locally with little data may not require a database server and might benefit from avoiding the complexities of a database server, however a larger web based app which requires tonnes of JSON files and has high traffic likely would benefit from a database server. It's really about assessing the needs of the project and deciding what's right for it.

Using a file system based approach as the app scales up you may need to implement things like caching, querying, and eventually clustering, etc. Why do this when it's already been implemented by someone else, and their server will likely be more optimized that something you've written unless you spend quite a bit of time on it.